# combining 100,000 csv files and adding missing information on each iteration

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm writing a code which pulls together around 100,000 text files and adds missing data. Calling pandas df each iteration is slow, is there a more recommended way?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(resultsDir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            resultsFile = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file))
            df = pd.read_csv(resultsFile, delimiter='\t')
            # parsePath data
            df['path'] = resultsFile
            df['resultsFile'] = file
            pathLvls = resultsFile.split(os.sep)
            df['sdCard'] = pathLvls[-3][:5]
            df['site'] = pathLvls[-3][6:]
            df['capture'] = pathLvls[-4]
            if not os.path.isfile(resultsFile):
                print(f' resultsFile {resultsFile} is missing')
            if df.empty:
                breakpoint()
                print(f'{resultsFile} empty results file')
                df['error'] = "empty results file"
            else:
                df2 = pd.concat([df2, df], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: If you have 100,000 files to read and process independently, I would consider multiprocessing.

Comment: Nothing here seems to require or benefit from using Pandas. I doubt dropping it will make any perceptible difference for the processing speed, as this is almost certainly I/O bound anyway. A faster disk (SSD instead of trad spinning rust, for example) is the way to make disk I/O faster.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Doubtful, but might be worth a quick experiment. Parallelizing CPU will not make I/O any faster.

Comment: you would need to use `threading` or `asyncio` modules since the delay will be in the i/o process in accessing the separate files.

Comment: @tripleee A quick test might be to time reading the files serially and time reading them in parallel to see if the disks are good enough for parallelisation. I.e. `time wc *.txt` and `time parallel wc ::: *.txt`

Comment: Does your code show the "combining" aspect of your question? I see you iterating over the set of files, but it's not clear what you do with each df... save the individual df back to the original file, append the df to something else?

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be one with `threading` or `asyncio` for i/o based operations.

here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import threading
import queue
import time

file_list = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', ...] # List of n file paths

def load_file(file, queue):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    queue.put(df)

q = queue.Queue() 

threads = []
for f in file_list:
    t = threading.Thread(target=load_file, args=(f, q)) 
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
    df = df.append(q.get())
    
print(df)
```

basically, like this:

- Use a queue to share loaded DataFrames between threads
- one thread per file (i have never tried 100,000 threads)
- join all threads to wait for completion

You would need to use your `os.walk()` to populate the list etc.

Comment: I can't imagine creating a new thread for each file is a good idea. Personally, I would try a pool first.

Comment: @MarkSetchell,  there are a few ways. i might expect someone also to suggest an `asyncio` method also. The key point is that it is an i/o based operation that these methods are well suited to.  But, your comment is noted.

Comment: Thank you - I'll give this a try - I've used pool a lot but got an odd result when I tried to pass a df through the queue. I'll look a but more and write back.